# How to avoid Web Service timeout

Tags: c#, linq, web-services, asmx

I have a .asmx web service which will be called by a third party client.

The web service exposes a method that looks something like the following:

```
int SaveMessages(int a,int b,int c, SomeArray[] somearray)
```

I would need to save all the above parameters into the DB.

But while saving I need to convert a particular field in the entity SomeArray[] before saving into the DB, for which I would need to check the value of the field and then get the corresponding value from another table, which will have more than 100,000 records. IN prod I am afraid of the service getting timed out, is there any way make that step of changing the field quick so that it will not get timed out

I have written a LINQ query to create the entity to save:

```
ar xyz = from x in somearray
          select new 
           {
              a= a,
              b=b,
              c=c,
              d= x.p,
              e = GetAlternateValue(x.q) // this will search a table with more than 100,000 records
           }
```

Comment: Increase `timeout` time of webservice

Comment: @RohitVyas thanks but the client is not interested in doing that, we have to go through lot of procedures even for a simple change

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, thanks but the client is a third party application who donot understand WCF concepts, they are kind of oldskool guys

Comment: What "WCF concepts"? You can do the exact same thing in WCF as with ASMX, it will simply be better-supported and faster and more flexible.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, actually the way it works b/w us is, we give them a WSDl file for .asmx service using which they create a proxy class and use our service, but we tried giving the a WSDL file for wcf service they were not able to understand it !

Comment: You seem to have reached the wrong conclusion. It's not that they can't understand WCF - it's that you don't understand how to make a WCF service that they will understand.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `GetAlternateValue` will be called for every item in the array. You might consider sending down the complete array to the DB and do the filtering there in one call instead.